# How to select pop up message "Allow" which is Span element of HTML page. Solution is expected by using find_element_by_css_selector

Tags: python, html, selenium, ui-automation

I am very new to Web UI automation, my queries might be very basic.
My UI automation requirement,I have to click on 'Allow' Pop up message. Could you please help me that How I can do this will work, I have given following try, However, unfortunately, these try did not work.

Following things could not worked. :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.instructions.ALLOW').click();




        ##

        #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.instructions').click()
        document = 'ALLOW'
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[normalize-space()='"+document+"']").click();

        #driver.findElement_by_xpath("//span[contains(., \"" + document + "\")]").click();
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'ALLOW')]/span").click(); ##2
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'ALLOW')]").click(); ##2
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'ALLOW')]").click()
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Allow')]").click() 
        #//a[contains(text(), 'Created By Me')]/span
        #section.hidden.MouseAllowCameraView
        #content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('section.MouseAllowCameraView').click()
```

=========HTML Code ===========

```
<section class="MouseAllowCameraView hidden"><div class="background"></div>
<div class="page">

    <div class="content">

        <p class="instructions"><bdo dir="ltr">Activate your webcam by clicking <span>**ALLOW**</span><br>at the top of your browser window.</bdo></p>

    </div>

    <div class="webcam-arrow"></div>

</div>
</section>
```

===================End HTML Code

Answer (score 1):

After checking the site, your question became more clear to me and its answer too. 
[Your Site](http://%20justareflektor.com) has to be open only in *Google Chrome*, Once we click on *Start* Button it pops-up a browser pop-up which request a user to click on '*Allow*' to proceed further,

Now here is the actual problem.

Selenium so far is not capable of automating the controls of the Browsers(Favorite bar, Address bar,Menu options) and the window which we get on clicking on '*Start*'button is a part of the controls of our *chrome* browser.

To handle this situation you can use Some third part tools like **Sikuli**,**AutoIT** or **ROBOT**.

I'll suggest to go with *Sikuli*, with the help of this you will be able to click on Allow button. 
Here is the complete Sikuli [Link1](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-1/) and [Link2](http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/) tutorial.

Please let me know if any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the given solution to my  queries. However, I have added your code, then following error has thrown...    "Unhandled ElementNotVisibleException: "                                                             graphics_WebGLHDMIChrome.justareflektorOpenCameraMouseMove                            FAIL: Unhandled ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'element not visible\n  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2265.0)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13 (132ec988536bd3b30838fdc1ef8fe01454727cab),platform=Linux 3.10.18 x86_64)'

Comment: Yes, this web site is publicly  available and its URL is  https://www.justareflektor.com/

Comment: Please check the above modified answer.

Comment: Thank you Rupesh for suggestion.  This requirement is a part autotest framework test automation using Python. I am not sure, How / whether I can use 'Sikuli' for this kind of solution.  Could you please let me know if any another solution by using existing python lib ... I am using Ubuntu Linux OS.. and Chromium OS...

Comment: Please use the link http://www.sikulix.com/quickstart.html  to start with Sikuli. About your System configurations, Yes it is compatible, Infact Python is the first language for Sikuli and you can use it Linux and Unix. From the Link you can download all the required files for Sikuli. It very easy to use. Just save the Sikuli jar files in your project libraries and start using it.

Comment: Thank you very much Rupesh for you suggestion. I will try to use Sikulix and let you know once I Integrate it to my project.

Comment: Hi Rupesh,  I am very much new to this webUI automaton. It would be great if you could suggest some solution to automate the following web link's span controls.                                                 1. the  below Head-Coupled 3D Demo  file Browsing using the below link 
"http://sheepeuh.com/particles/"
2. I have to automate the  changes which are the settings over on the browser top right corner     For example:  I have change

Comment: Hi Rupesh,  I am very much new to this webUI automaton. It would be great if you could suggest some solution to automate the following web link's span controls.                                                 1. the  below Head-Coupled 3D Demo  file Browsing using the below link 
"http://sheepeuh.com/particles/"
2. I have to automate the  changes which are the settings over on the browser top right corner     For example:  I have change  'Alpha' span slider     value like 20 % . How this can be automate using selenium-python  like driver. findElement_by_xpath ()